# Error inserting a record into two Tables with a FK relationship using Phalcon

Tags: php, mysql, database, phalcon

I have two tables in my MySQL database, which were created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int auto_increment,
  name varchar(10),
  primary key(id)
) engine=innodb
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id_fk int,
  stuff varchar(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_fk`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id_fk) REFERENCES table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) engine=innodb
```

(These are not the original tables. The point is that table2 has a foreign key referencing the primary key in table 1)

Now in my code, I would like to add entries to both of the tables within one transaction. I'm doing this:

```
                $table1 = new table1();
                $table1->setTransaction($transaction);
                $table1->name($name);


                if (!$table->create()) {
                    foreach ($table1->getMessages() as $message) {
                    $this->flash->error($message);
                }
                    $transaction->rollback("Can't save table1");
                } else {
                $table2 = new table2();
                $table2->setTransaction($transaction);
                $table2->setId($table1->getId());
                $table2->setStuff($stuff);
                if (!$table2->create()) {
                    foreach ($table2->getMessages() as $message) {
                        $this->flash->error($message);
                    }
                    $transaction->rollback("Can't save password");
                }
                $transaction->commit();
```

The table1 create() is successful, however, when I attempt the table2 create, it always errors out with a Constraint Violation stating that the Value of field "Id" does not exist on referenced table.How can I use phalcon transaction to save data into two referenced tables in a single transaction. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is: ConstraintViolation, Value of field "Id" does not exist on referenced table

Comment: This was solved; http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2056/two-tables-fk-on-pk-created-in-same-transaction